# Does OpenGL needs normals to make shadows?

Tags: opengl

Can someone explain me why does addition of following lines

```
glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
```

to code

```
    glewInit();
    glEnable ( GL_LIGHTING ) ;
    glEnable ( GL_COLOR_MATERIAL ) ;
    glColorMaterial ( GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE ) ;
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_GREATER);

    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glCullFace(GL_BACK);

    glClearDepth(0);


    GLuint vertexbuffer;

    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,vertexbuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(float)*Loader.verticesFixed.size(),&Loader.verticesFixed[0],GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,vertexbuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(
            0,                  // attribute 0. No particular reason for 0, but must match the layout in the shader.
            3,                  // size
            GL_FLOAT,           // type
            GL_FALSE,           // normalized?
            12,                  // stride
            (void*)(0)            // array buffer offset
        );
 glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES,0,Loader.verticesFixed.size()/3);
```

turns this model:
[image]

into this model with shadows:

[image]

I didn't provide any normal data and I was told that OpenGL doesn't calculate normals. But then how did I get proper light effects with shadows on model? Am I mistaken thinking that normals are needed for shadows or OpenGL do calculate normals?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me, it looks like it's just the normal Attenuation formula being applied without normals. Light strength will diminish over distance, so portions of the model further away are darker.

Now, if you *were* using normals, you'd see proper shading, i.e. only faces pointing towards the source of the light would get lit up, and the more the light direction is perpendicular to the normal, the stronger the lighting. Without normals, I assume it's just ignoring the normals entirely.

Incidentally, you can add this to the very, *very* long list of reasons why you should be using the Programmable Pipeline to render objects, as if you had to implement the (quite simple; is usually about 5-15 lines of code for me) lighting algorithm yourself, you'd be able to know this right away. [Tutorial](http://www.learnopengl.com/#!Introduction)

Comment: Very interesting explanation. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In the fixed function pipeline provided by obsolete/compatibility OpenGL, you need to manually specify vertex normals with the `glNormal*` family of functions. If you don't specify the normals, OpenGL will use some default value.

In the programmable pipeline provided by core, modern OpenGL, you would implement whatever lighting model you want in shaders. If you want to use normals, you'd specify them as a generic vertex attribute.

The only thing that OpenGL computes normals for is back face culling, as controlled by `glCullFace`.